# Calling multiple lambdas and return aggregated result

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to implement functionality:

1. Receive api request
2. From the input, create X different cases
3. For each case, do calculation
4. Aggregate all results, and send result back to api gateway

First guess was using Step Functions, but this service has limit for 32kb of data transferred between steps, which is not working for me. Also, since I have about 10 steps, I assume it would be hard to implement and also expensive to try to use S3 for storage of this inter-steps data.
Second guess was calling multiple lambdas from single lambda, and wait for all responses. Since I use AWS C++ SDK, it seems a bit complicated since there is almost no documentation for c++ or good examples of this case.

The simplest solution for me would be to create multiple threads inside single lambda, but it supports only 2 cores, which is also not working for me, I need at least 50-100.

Do you have any other solution or idea, as simple as possible. Is it possible to use aws batch or sqs for this or something else?

Comment: unclear what is your problem? "protocol", C++ code?

Comment: I would like to know if there is some other way or aws service which could be used to solve this type of problem. Also, I am not sure if it is possible to call multiple lambdas (simultaneously) from single lambda and wait for results.

Comment: How calling lambda related to aws service?

Comment: @Dusan, what would be the total time required to process such a request, if it is single-threaded? If you have this code already working on a normal computer or on EC2, how long does it take to run there? And how often are such requests being received (eg once per minute?). I'm just trying to figure out whether Lambda is an appropriate choice for this requirement.

Comment: Time required to process this type of request depends upon input from user, so it could be 0.1s up to 300s. Also, since it will be public API, it means multiple users can call this API in the same time so I need it to scale appropriately.